# Why no temple dedicated to Chhatrapati Shivaji?

Tags: shiva, avatars

My Marathi friends are very passionate about Chhatrapati Shivaji as he's considered to be an avatara of Shiva.

There're many people who claim to be Shivaji's devotees, but still there's not even one temple dedicated to Shivaji in Maharashtra, let alone all of india.

Why is this the case ? Considering he's considered the ideal king by almost all hindus, and if Vivekananda Swami can be considered an avatar of Saptrishi, then why is Shivaji not similarly venerated ?

thanks . Yes this is a serious question

Comment: Are there any temples dedicated to Vivekananda Swami? Plus is there any mention of Shivaji as an avataar of Shiva anywhere in scriptures?

Comment: I am sure there're many later day saints who have no validation in scriptures, but they have a very successful fan following and their temples decorated with gold. Sai Baba of Shirdi is one such saint. 
Yes , there're some temples of Swami Vivekananda , atleast some vedanta centers where idols of swami vivekananda along with his guru Swami Ramakrishna and Sharda Ma are placed

Comment: As the answer states below: Shivarajeshwar is the temple of Shivaji, built by his son Rajaram. This is also the only place where palm and foot print of Shivaji, taken in lime mortar and preserved. These were taken when he came to visit the fort after its completion.

Comment: If he is a Hindu God, there would be many. But you know he is a king. So.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma yes he's king , but in maharashtra ppl revere him a lot :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a temple of  [**Chhatrapati  Shivaji Maharaj**.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shivaji)  The temple is  the only one of it's kind in India at Sindhudurg Fort in Malvan -Kokan (coastal) Region of Maharashtra ,which is called "**ShivaRajeshwar" Mandir"**.

---

[image]

Shivarajeshwar is the temple of Shivaji, built by his son Rajaram. This is also the only place where palm and foot print of Shivaji, taken in lime mortar and preserved. These were taken when he came to visit the fort after its completion.

[**wikimapia**](http://wikimapia.org/18920737/Shri-Shivrajeshwar-Mandir-The-Only-Temple-Of-Shivaji-Maharaj-In-The-World)

Comment: @just_Do_It - Thanks for edit and improvement. Haven't added that part because it's more related to history.

Comment: I am assuming hindus, even outside maharashtra ,  do venerate this one king a lot more than most others. For obvious reasons